# Unable to run Tensorboard from command prompt

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

```
tensorboard --logdir=./model/ted500/summaries

Starting TensorBoard 28 on port 6006
```

Sometimes it shows the url here and some times it's stuck there. I'm new to tensorboard, so have followed couple of tutorials in order to run it but seems its still not working.

Can someone please advice how to launch tensorboard ?

Comment: view the tensorboard documentation, it clearly demonstrates how to start a session.

Comment: This question was answered well in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392195/how-do-i-launch-tensorboard

Comment: See response to this question that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985835/tensorboard-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 10):

Generally we launch Tensorboard by writing:-

```
tensorboard --logdir='/your/path/here'
```

It may happen that some processes are using the port currently you are invoking for tensorboard. So, you can try changing the port at which tensorboard starts by writing:-

```
tensorboard --logdir='/your/path/here' --port=xxxx
```

write any unused port (Range:0 to 65535) in place of `xxxx`.

You can see the logs of tensorboard in terminal by writing:-

```
tensorboard --logdir='/your/path/here' --port=xxxx --debug
```

maybe it could help you.