# 'tensorboard' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

Just started using Tensorflow, but I am not able to use tensorboard command on my cmd, it gives the error command

```
C:\Users\tushar\PycharmProjects>tensorboard --logdir="NewTF"
'tensorboard' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

I am using window 10 and have installed tensorboard library/

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem for tensorflow 1.5.0 and windows10.

Following [tensor documentation ("Launching TensorBoard" section)](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard), you can try:

```
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=[PATH_TO_LOGDIR]
```

Now tensorboard is working properly for me.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I don't know if your answer would solve the OP's problem, but I do know that communication is just as important here. Putting the actions before the "I had the same problem..." bit makes it easier to read, and less likely to get closed as "not really an answer."

Comment: @RoB what is this path_to_logrid? where do I find it?

Comment: For your training process you can define some path:

`path2logdir = "some/path"`

. Next you define a writer: 

`writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(path2logdir, sess.graph)`

 and within training process you can save some useful stats:

`writer.add_summary(train_stats, iteration)`

 where train_stats is a result from training process wanted to see in tensorboard. I hope everything is clear now.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Anaconda prompt
2. activate tensorflow environment e.g. activate Test1-Tensor

   [image]
3. tensorboard --logdir=path to your log files, 
   put entire path. e.g.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I also realized that instead of opening Anaconda prompt, I can use normal one but I have to go to **C:/Users/myName** before to call tensorboard --logdir=path

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and this is what I did.

The best way to open tensorboard on Windows on a specified port is

Step 1: Open CMD

Step 2: Type the following command

```
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=<path to log file> --port=6006
```

The --logdir option is to specify the log location for tensorboard and --port option is to specify the port on which you want tensorboard to run.

I have chosen port 6006 for tensorboard which used to be the default port. (I got an error when I didn't specify the port).

You will get a warning if CUDA is not installed on your machine, for now it can be ignored.

Step 3: Once the command successfully executes the output looks like this

```
Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.2.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Step 4: Just open your browser to http://localhost:6006/

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same sort of problem while running tensorboard from cmd, if your tensorflow installation was done using conda, then you can launch tensorboard from the Anaconda prompt as follows:

```
activate tensorflow
tensorboard --logdir=path to your log files
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to open launch TensorBoard with Anaconda Enviroment**

*First make sure that you are downloaded PACKAGE of tensorboard*

**1. Open Anaconda**

[image]

**2. Click on PLAY button , then you will see "Open Terminal" and click
3. Go to your main project directory (where you store logs directory)**

[image]

**4. Call following python script to launch TensorBoard**

```
#EXAMPLE (python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=logs/)
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir='your log dir'
```

**5. FINISH**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`C:\Users\tushar\PycharmProjects>python -m tensorflow.tensorboard --logdir="NewTF"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) as your python environment, make sure to activate it before trying to open tensorboard.

Would look like this in your case:

```
C:\Users\tushar\PycharmProjects>conda activate YourCondaEnv && tensorboard --logdir="NewTF"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed TensorboardX and are still encountering this problem, it appears that you have not yet installed TensorBoard.

> pip install tensorboard

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33944141)

Answer (score 0):

Just open your anaconda prompt and head to the respective logs folder. Make sure to activate the tensorflow environment in the prompt and then just write

```
tensorboard --logdir logs
```

It worked for me.

Peace

Comment: According to the question, `tensorboard` isn't recognized in command prompt.