# Opening tensorboard saved scalars on windows

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am using Pytorch on Windows 10 OS, and having trouble understanding the correct use of [Pytorch TensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch).

After instantiating a writer (`writer = SummaryWriter()`), and adding the value of the loss function (in every iteration) to it (`write.add_scalar('data/loss_func', loss.data[0].item(), iteration)`), I have a folder which contains the saved run.

My questions are:

1) As far as I understand, after the training is complete, I need to write in the terminal (which corresponds to the command line prompt in Windows):

```
tensorboard --logdir=C:\Users\DrJohn\Documents\runs
```

where this is the folder which contains the file created by tensorboardX. What is the valid syntax in Windows command prompt? I couldn't understand this from the online tutorials

2) Is it possible to see the learning during the training, by using tensorboardX? (i.e. to plot the learning curve during the iterations?)Is the only option is to see everything once the training ends?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `tensorboard --logdir="C:\Users\DrJohn\Documents\runs"` from `C:\`, you can call it during training, to monitor your loss

Comment: The following error appears - 'tensorboard' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This is although I have installed tensorflow. Hot can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985835/tensorboard-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!