# How do I launch Tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am following the introductory guide on Tensorflow at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro, and managed to create an 'events.out' file by using

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.')
writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
writer.flush()
```

in my python file and running it. The next step is to launch Tensorboard in a 'terminal' with the 'shell command' `tensorboard --logdir`. How to do this? What terminal am I supposed to use? I tried windows powershell but it does not seem to work. It gives the error

> tensorboard : The term 'tensorboard' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable prog ram. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + tensorboard --logdir
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tensorboard:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Comment: Yes I have installed tensorflow.

Comment: Are you running the Python code in a Jupyter Notebook? And if so, have you activated the same (virtual) environment when you're running tensorboard on the command line?

Comment: In Windows, perhaps you need to add the Tensorboard directory into the path variables, or provide the full location to the tensorboard.exe, or use other terminals like Anaconda Prompt or Git CMD. Both Anaconda Prompt and Git CMD worked on my Win7 desktop.

Comment: @bartcode  No I just run it directly with python.exe. What is the advantage of Jupyter and how do I use it?

Comment: @QwertYuiop, well, I merely asked because the Python kernel Jupyter uses might sometimes be a bit confusing. You might want to check whether you're actually using the same Python executable using: `import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))` and/or checking whether the used `site-packages` location is the same using: `import site; print(site.getsitepackages())`.

Answer (score -1):

Using PowerShell is fine. It sounds like your PATH is not configured to find the Tensorboard binary like others are saying. Can you show me what you get for `pip show tensorflow`? It should have something like below:

```
(1) ➜  ~ pip show tensorflow
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\stephanwlee\venv\tf\lib\site-packages
Requires: enum34, keras-preprocessing, wheel, astor, backports.weakref, mock, tensorboard, termcolor, protobuf, gast, absl-py, grpcio, six, keras-applications, numpy
Required-by:
```

In above output, location is the important piece that tells you where binaries are roughly gets placed. If you are using virtualenv like the TensorFlow installation guide (everything should be set up seamlessly and I would recommend you to use it), the binaries should be in `c:\users\stephanwlee\venv\tf\Scripts`. Please check and see if the path is in `$env:path`.

If any of these didn't help, please do add result of `pip show tensorflow` and `$env:path` from PowerShell in the response, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.7.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\luis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, protobuf, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wheel, wrapt
Required-by:
   LUIS@XEONE5-2620-v2  ~ 
❯
   LUIS@XEONE5-2620-v2  ~ 
❯ $env:path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cracklock\Bin;C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;;C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes;D:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).